# Show only 1 direction for Google Maps embed API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-embed

For a school project we are making an application that can track the location of a garbage truck.

To calculate the fastest direction for the truck we are using the Google Maps embed API, but there is one "problem". The API returns 3 optional directions but we only need one.

Is there an possibility to show only one direction, or do we need the JavaScript API of Google Maps then?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Google Maps JavaScript API. I am using it for my website and it works like a charm, with many functionalities.